# Test to see if Python LDAP connection works

Tags: python, django, python-ldap

In our applications at work, we have a CAS backend for authentication and then we store data about the user that we would like to retrieve from a LDAP server. To facilitate that we have a custom `backends.py` with our own backend for authentication. This Backend extends the [Django-CAS backend](https://bitbucket.org/cpcc/django-cas/overview). In order to not have to reconnect to an LDAP server every time we store the LDAP connection to a class variable and see if that exists. If it does, then we reuse that one.

```
if not hasattr(PopulatedCASBackend, 'ldap_server'):
    PopulatedCASBackend.ldap_server = ldap.initialize(settings.LDAP_SERVER_URL)
    PopulatedCASBackend.ldap_server.simple_bind_s()
```

We have found out though, that after some amount of time, LDAP will consider this connection dead, and refuse to use this connection. So I decided to add an else statement to the code

```
else :
# we are trying to see if our current connection isn't stale. If it is, close it and remake
    try :
        user_data = ldap_server.search_s(
                        # all the correct params to search
                    )
    except:
        #connection is stale, so remake a new connection
        PopulatedCASBackend.ldap_server.unbind_s()
        PopulatedCASBackend.ldap_server = ldap.initialize(settings.LDAP_SERVER_URL)
        PopulatedCASBackend.ldap_server.simple_bind_s()
```

My question is then, is there a better way to accomplish this? I understand that this works, but that means that each time I do this I must run a search twice (or I suppose I could use the data returned from this either way...) Regardless, I feel like this is hackish, where in order to see if the connection is not going to work, I `try` then fix it if it didn't go. Is there a better way?